# I can't include boost header files in my own header

Tags: c++, boost, header, include

util.h

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

namespace core {
    class Config {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
....
```

I get the error:

> Error 2   error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp': No such file or
>   directory d:\path\kserver\lib\util.h  1   1   kserver

The full list of options for compiling is:

```
/GS /TP /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"D:\Development\Tools\boost_1_57_0" /Zi /Gm- /Od /Ob0 /Fd"core.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR /Gd /MDd /Fa"Debug/" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"core.dir\Debug\" /Fp"core.dir\Debug\core.pch"
```

If I include `ptree.hpp` in the cpp file it works fine.

How can I define a variable in my header file? Please note that the question is not specific to `ptree`.

**UPDATE:**

I figured out what it is. My solution is several projects where one is a library used by the main project. The lib header includes the `boost` header file. When including the header file in my main project the hpp can not be found... this means that to build the main project I have to do one of two things:

1. Include the boost headers to the main project too
2. Remove the header includes and not expose a boost variable to the main project

Is there another option so I can still keep the include in the header file?

Answer (score 1):

hide the implementation details of your library. use the PIMPL idiom also called [Opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B). the exposed header of your library shall contain only the public interface plus a private implementation pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The include paths are probably

- not the same for the header and the source files
- relative. If the header is in a different path than the source then the relative path could effectively point to the wrong place

Comment: the headers and source files are in the same folder. i don't really know how it is possible to have different include for source and headers.

Answer (score 0):

From error you post It seems either development library for boost is not installed on your machine and if it is installed then your compiler is not configured properly to read it from its installation directory.

Comment: As I said, it works fine but only when including in the source file. Not the header though...

Comment: msbuild project.sln :) I'm using visual studio 2013. The project is created with cmake.

Comment: I've added the compilation options in the question